# Unable to install jQuery gem to rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to add jQuery to my rails project by using this command:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and I am receiving this error :

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Unknown command jquery-rails
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas on how to get this to work.

Comment: gem 'jquery-rails' is not a command .. it's a line to put in the gemfile file.

Comment: You should run this command on the terminal `gem install jquery-rails`. For more info over ruby gems look up to this [link](https://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#installing-gems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in gem file

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

OR in terminal

```
gem install jquery-rails
```

then bundle install

in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Answer (score 3):

`gem 'jquery-rails'` is not a command.

Add this line to your Gemfile and then run command: `bundle install`

**OR**

You can also install this gem by running command: `gem install jquery-rails`